# Storing large string in Salesforce

Tags: apex, oauth2, metadata, dml

I am currently handling an oAuth 2.0 PKCE authentication flow (not supported by Named Credentials). At the end I get an `access_token` that is around ~1200 chars, this token lasts for about 30 minutes and may need to be updated mid-flight, it is also usable org wide.

Where should I store it? Is there an option I haven't considered?

There are the places I've considered

**Platform Cache**

- This seemed like the most obvious place, it only lasts for a short period, I need it org wide, and 1200 chars will easily fit within 1MB partition. The downside is that it excludes Professional editions and is a bit of a pain to setup in scratch orgs and developer editions.

**Custom Settings**

- Cannot fit a string this big into a single field :(

**Custom Metadata**

- I need to be able to update this token up to every 30mins, this is a poor use case for custom metadata, I can use the metadata API to update these values, but that's a pain and might interfere with total HTTP callouts

**Custom SObject**

- These tokens are used exclusively during HTTP callouts and DML and HTTP callouts don't mix well if the token requires updating.
- This also involves at least 1 SOQL query just to get the token which is also not ideal.

Comment: Why is Custom SObject not iddeal for that? For fetching or updating Custom SObject you can use `REST` apis , so that u dont have to mix DML and HTTP callouts.

Comment: Custom Object is our vote: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270811/apex-callout-to-an-openid-connect-endpoint-protected-by-pkce-code-challenge

Comment: yes i agrre with @nagedra Singh above, sobjects are not ideals way to store Access tokens. use the custom setting, it's best way to update and use the Access tokens, 
if it's about storage, make two/three fields. and concatenate  them while accessing/updating/ split the access token and store it in two different fields.

Comment: Maybe this could work:

1) Create an Apex Custom Auth Provider and reference it in your Named Credentials.
2) I have seen scenarios where named credentials storing more than 3000+ char access tokens.

Here is the link to the sample Custom Auth Provider Code. This sample code for client credentials flow. A similar code needs to be developed for the oAuth 2.0 PKCE authentication flow.
https://github.com/bobbywhitesfdc/ApigeeAuthProvider

Comment: That's a really interesting approach @H R. I'll experiment with that approach, it sounds ideal, I didn't realise you could use auth providers and named credentials in that fashion